# How to maintain passwords when traveling?

Tags: security

I'm traveling out of the country and I don't want to bring my laptop, because I would then worry about it getting stolen or broken. I am bringing an old iPad so that I can check email and look up restaurants, etc. while on the trip, but if it got destroyed it wouldn't be a big deal.

I don't plan to access my bank or other secured websites, but I'm thinking that I might need to if there were some kind of emergency that I needed to deal with. But my bank website has a unique password (plus two factor security) and that password is written down in a file on my computer and not synced to any cloud service.

If I don't bring a copy of that file, I don't know the password (it's random gibberish, to prevent standard exploits). But if I do bring a copy of that file, and anyone got that copy away from me, it would be horrific, because they would get passwords to everything.

So how could I work this? I could put the file on a USB stick, with encryption, but since I won't have my own computer, I can't read it without trusting someone else's, and that would be a huge risk.

I could put the file on the iPad itself, but then if that got stolen, I would worry that someone could access the file. (For that matter, how can I secure the email app on the iPad?)

What is a good way to handle this situation?

Comment: Not sure what kind of file or encryption you're talking about but the obvious choice is to use a password manager. Keepass to name one is available on Android and iOS and can be carried on a USB stick without the need to install anything. Also, I am not sure what your concern with the USB stick is: if you do have to use that password, you have to trust the computer and the browser, no way around that. I have a special email account of travel bookings and use on the go. My “main“ email accounts (e.g. recovery email for essential accounts) is not configured in my phone's email accounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some ideas.

You don't have to take the whole file with you, just a file with that specific password.

You can obfuscate the password (whether on paper or in a file). What I mean is that, for example, you can write a `b` instead of an `a`, and a `c` instead of a `b` etc.

You can use an offline password manager and remember some password/passphrase.

You can encrypt the file.

If you choose to use a password manger or encrypt the file, you can store *that* new password on paper and keep it separate from the iPad, and can obfuscate it as well.

Perhaps worth reading - [an answer about storing passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15733/what-is-a-good-practical-and-sane-way-to-manage-all-your-passwords-for-online/19648#19648) by a top contributor on security.stackexchange.

Comment: I especially like this suggestion "You can obfuscate the password". This gives the OP a method they can select for keeping the password available - BUT a simple cipher key like this can be kept in their head - and therefore be next to unbreakable!  *NICE*